# Firewall completely disabled but still cant access port - Centos7

Tags: iptables, centos7, ufw, firewalld

I have disabled selinux in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

rebooted and disabled both `firewalld` and `iptables` services.

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)

# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) 

# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I still can't access the server using a specific port:

```
# nc -v 10.0.12.3 8887
nc: connect to 10.0.12.3 port 8887 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I can ping the server and ssh to it.

I have tried opening ports using `iptables` and `firewalld` and haven't managed to make it work. The last option remaining is to disable the firewall completely and even that doesn't work.

the ports that are being listened on are:

```
# netstat -plnt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1031/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1843/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1392/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1391/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1756/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1892/sshd: jmalapra 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2461/sshd: jmalapra 
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1031/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1392/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1391/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::6010                 :::*                    LISTEN      1892/sshd: jmalapra 
tcp6       0      0 :::6011                 :::*                    LISTEN      2461/sshd: jmalapra
```

Comment: The server can only show a connection is accepted if a program listens on the port. In this case Jupyter notebook needed to listen on port 8887 for nc to show that the port was open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `netstat` or `ss` to verify that a service is listening on the ip/port in question.

*edit* now that you verified that the service in question is running, reset your box' security measures:

```
# Restore SELinux
sed -i -e 's/SELINUX=disabled/SELINUX=enforcing/g' /etc/sysconfig/selinux
touch /.autorelabel
reboot

# Firewall exception
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8887/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --reload

# Remove superfluous packages
yum remove -y iptables-services ufw
```

Comment: I added the output of `netstat -plnt` in the original post. It seems like it isn't listening on that port. How can I get this port to be listened to without requiring the firewall? Or, do I need the firewall?

Comment: I had to first run the application, in this case jupyter notebook on the server which listens on port 8887 for nc to show that it port is open.

Comment: Now you should reactivate the firewall and properly open the port through it.  firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8887/tcp --permanent  ;firewall-cmd --reload